# Why does the code stop and abort the execution with pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, file, pointers, realloc

I need to alloc memory to a struct called Locadoras and in execution it's saying /dorun.sh: line 71:  2692 Aborted (core dumped) sh "${SHFILE}". I have tried in Netbeans and Codeblocks, same error in C.
Here's the codes:

Main.c

```
Locadoras *filmes;
filmes = malloc(sizeof (Locadoras));
LerArquivoBinarioFilmes(filmes);
```

TransacoesFilmes.c

```
void LerArquivoBinarioFilmes(Locadoras *filme) {
    FILE * arq;
    arq = fopen("DadosLocadora.bin", "rb");
    int cont = 1;
    if (arq != NULL) {
        while (1) {
            size_t tam = fread(filme, sizeof (Locadoras), 1, arq);
            if (tam < 1) {
                break;
            }
            cont++;
            realloc(filme, sizeof (Locadoras) * cont);
        }
    } else {
        printf("error");
        exit(1);
    }
    fclose(arq);
}
```

Comment: Ignoring the return value of `realloc` can't be good.

Comment: Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Neither NetBeans nor Codeblocks are C compilers, but both probably use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

Comment: Your last `printf` could be replaced by `perror`

Comment: when asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem, so we can help you.

Comment: error messages should be output to `stderr` rather than `stdout` and when the error is from a C library function, should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror()` outputs both yor error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
realloc(filme, sizeof (Locadoras) * cont);
```

The function `realloc` returns (when successful) a pointer to the newly allocated memory and has copied the contents of the prior memory into the newly allocated memory.  However, it can fail.  When it fails, it returns a NULL pointer

1. the code must first check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful
2. only when `realloc` is successful is it safe to assign the target pointer from the returned value

As an example

```
void *temp = realloc(filme, sizeof (Locadoras) cont);
if( !temp )
{
    perror( "realloc failed" );
    free( filme );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, realloc successful

filme = temp;
```

Note:

1. `free()` is found in `stdlib.h`
2. `perror()` is found in `stdio.h`
3. `exit()` is found in `stdlib.h`
4. `EXIT_FAILURE` is found in `stdlib.h`

Comment: Also `LerArquivoBinarioFilmes()` should return resulting value of `filme` pointer to caller.

Comment: @ReAl, your correct, so this line in `main()` `LerArquivoBinarioFilmes(filmes);` should be: `filmes = LerArquivoBinarioFilmes(filmes);`  which means the signature for the sub function should return `Locadoras*` not `void`, etc